# Permissions error trying to log to file in Docker

Tags: docker, celery

I am working on a legacy Docker application that is using Celery workers.  I'm  trying to log to a file using the link below as a guide.  The code shown below gives the error shown below.  How do I fix this permission error so I can log to a file from a Celery worker running in Docker?

**Logging Example:**

https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-logging-messages-to-both-stdout-and-to-a-file-in-python

**Code:**

```
import logging
import sys

from datetime import datetime


def log(msg):
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    a_logger = logging.getLogger()
    a_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    output_file_handler = logging.FileHandler("/output.log")
    stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

    a_logger.addHandler(output_file_handler)
    a_logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
```

**Error:**

```
2021-12-27T17:44:15.581091247Z  [entityservice.tasks.encoding_uploading] dp_id=4 pid=d96b692bd0bb825a1c5192bf011d4678d198c7031bef9bdd task_name=handle_raw_upload
2021-12-27T17:44:15.597793842Z [2021-12-27 17:44:15,597: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] [info     ] An exception 'PermissionError' was raised in a task [entityservice.tasks] dp_id=4 pid=d96b692bd0bb825a1c5192bf011d4678d198c7031bef9bdd task_name=handle_raw_upload
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601376502Z [2021-12-27 17:44:15,601: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] [error    ] Unexpected exception raised in task 8782a9bf-b06c-40cd-aba2-c348f978ad04 [entityservice.tasks] dp_id=4 pid=d96b692bd0bb825a1c5192bf011d4678d198c7031bef9bdd task_name=handle_raw_upload
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601393477Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601395948Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601397925Z     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601399652Z   File "/opt/project/backend/entityservice/tasks/base_task.py", line 87, in __call__
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601401417Z     return super(TracedTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601403246Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601405043Z     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601409390Z   File "/opt/project/backend/entityservice/tasks/encoding_uploading.py", line 189, in handle_raw_upload
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601411376Z     lrp.log("Starting run")
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601413300Z   File "/opt/project/backend/entityservice/util/logger/lrp_logger.py", line 13, in log
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601427156Z     output_file_handler = logging.FileHandler("/output.log")
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601428795Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1146, in __init__
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601430304Z     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601431718Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1175, in _open
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601433261Z     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,
2021-12-27T17:44:15.601434757Z PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/output.log'
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604703127Z [2021-12-27 17:44:15,601: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task entityservice.tasks.encoding_uploading.handle_raw_upload[8782a9bf-b06c-40cd-aba2-c348f978ad04] raised unexpected: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604715796Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604717644Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604719313Z     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604720826Z   File "/opt/project/backend/entityservice/tasks/base_task.py", line 87, in __call__
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604722363Z     return super(TracedTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604723854Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604725388Z     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604726813Z   File "/opt/project/backend/entityservice/tasks/encoding_uploading.py", line 189, in handle_raw_upload
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604728328Z     lrp.log("Starting run")
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604729813Z   File "/opt/project/backend/entityservice/util/logger/lrp_logger.py", line 13, in log
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604731366Z     output_file_handler = logging.FileHandler("/output.log")
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604732845Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1146, in __init__
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604734331Z     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604735748Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1175, in _open
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604737188Z     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,
2021-12-27T17:44:15.604738714Z PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/output.log'
2021-12-27T17:44:17.607382675Z [2021-12-27 17:44:17,606: DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2] Using selector: EpollSelector
```

Comment: "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/output.log'" The user as which python runs must be able to write to that file.  I would recommend you let your celery workers write to stdout and use the standard docker logging procedures.  Docker containers are best considered ephemeral.  But if you really want to write to a log file, the best way is probably to create a dedicated directory for it (say `/var/log/myprogram` ) within the Dockerfile, and change the owner of that directory to the user under which python runs.  But seriously, don't log to your docker volume, pain lies that way.

Comment: Are there tools that will do things like write all of the output of stdout to one file and only info level logging to a separate file?